# What is "This location cannot be displayed." telling me with regard to portable USB drive?

Tags: usb, drive

I have a Western Digital MY Passport Ultra 2GB drive. I plugged it in and got a popup dialog that said:

**This location could not be displayed.**
Sorry, could not display all the contents of "36D2920FD292D410":
Error when getting information for file
'media/user/36D2920FD292D410/bin': Input/output error

But this error went away after just repeatedly clicking the drive icon in the Files application and re-inserting the USB cable a time or two. I have no idea what changed things. I was then able to copy my home directory to the drive. But it took a long time and when I came back to it in the morning the computer had shut down for some reason.

Now I get the error message again and it isn't going away. How do I handle this error message?

EDIT: I tried this drive in my Windows 10 computer and it also gives an error saying that a file or directory is unreadable. I am going to reformat it in Windows.

Comment: Yes, please do that, format again, and make sure you haven't enabled "dynamic disks" in Windows.

Comment: Your USB stick is dying.  Do a full low-level format under Ubuntu and if it survives that it's still good, otherwise you'll lose data pretty soon.

Comment: @Fabby could be the answer...